# Failed to deploy project. Operation_messages view for the operation identifier '33'

Tags: sql-server, ssis

ON the last phase of deploying my SSIS project, received this error. Ran the code

```
SELECT *
FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM
WHERE OM.operation_id = 33
```

Result: failed to deploy the project. Fix the problems and try again later. The specified parameter value string is too long. The string must be no more than 8000 characters.

Please help.

Comment: So you're trying to set a parameter value to a string longer than 8,000 characters - and this isn't permissible - what do you need help with? As a work around - if the string is  <16,000 chars you could just create two parameters and concatenate them as needed.

Comment: Oh no.. Everything was work perfect until the end process to Deploy the package.  The the program converted my Parameters to a project Parameter.  I searched on the error ID '33' and that's the error that showed that I have used more than 8000 characters (string).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or newer you can use **VARCHAR(MAX)**

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
```

varchar(max) should work just fine, the following is SQL:

```
declare @cmd varchar(max)
set @cmd = 'print /*' + replicate ('-', 7990);
set @cmd = @cmd + replicate ('-', 7990) + '*/ getdate()';
exec (@cmd)
print datalength (@cmd)
```